# Can a CUDA event be fired from device-side code?

Tags: cuda, cuda-events

Is there any way to fire an event (for benchmarking purposes, similar to cudaEvents in the CPU code) from a device kernel in CUDA?

E.g. suppose I would like to measure the time passed from kernel start to the first thread ever that starts a computation and the time passed from the last thread that leaves the computation to the CPU return.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device runtime API (used with dynamic parallelism) does have [limited stream and events support](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#events-cdp), but event timing is not supported.

So, no you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly workaround would be writing to some [managed-memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd) location, and having a host-side thread poll it and fire the event when the value changes.